# Check if entry is available in database

Tags: mysql, string

I have generated a 10 digit number, added it to a database after purchase.

Now I want to make a php page to give users an input box, ask them to enter the 10 digit number, and click submit. After you click submit it should return if the pin is used or has not been used it. (Used if its not available - Not used if its in the table)

I got the following code:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
function validated_pin($pin)
{   

    $pin = mysql_real_escape_string($pin);  // SECURITY!
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT pins FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1");
    if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    return 'This pin has already been used';
    } else {
    return 'This pin is available for use';
}
}

echo '<html><center>
<form action="' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '" method="post">
<table style="border:0px solid black;">
<tr>
<td>PIN*:</td><td><input type="text" name="pin" value="" class="bginput"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="submit" id ="submit" name="submit1" value="Check Pin>>" class="button"></td>
</tr>
</table>';          
                echo validated_pin($pin);
echo '</center></html>';
?>
```

And PHPmyAdmin looks like this:
http://gyazo.com/67c3df7171c83c677cb221c04d644ed7.png

It's located in _donation and in table name pins

I don't know whats going on tried looking everywhere

The current code will return this error

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/website/public_html/directory/example.php on line 8
```

Comment: This error usually occurs when a boolean value(false) is returned, meaning ur query was not able to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is-

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT pins FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1");
```

shouldn't it be

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1");
```

`pin` is the column name right? not `pins`

```
 if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

   if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    return 'This pin has already been used';
    else
    return 'This pin is available for use';
```

}

Comment: Using your 2nd code got rid of the error, but it still automatically displays "This pin is available for use" with out entering any value, and even if I do it always returns "This pin is available for use"

Comment: @Swaly- could u try that?

Comment: Just tried it, it's not showing "This pin is available for use" anymore but no matter what I enter nothing shows up

Comment: @Swaly... check again

Comment: Ehh sorry about that still nothing happens when I click Check Pin I think my error is related to my form and not my function

Comment: This seemed to have solved it:

    $pin = $_POST["pin"];
    
    function validated_pin($pin)
    {   
       
        $pin = mysql_real_escape_string($pin);  // SECURITY!
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1");
        
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            return 'This pin has already been used';
          } else {
         return 'This pin is available for use';
           } 
    }
    
Still facing the issue of it saying "Already been used" before I execute any code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is failing to fetch data, resulting in `false` returned.

Firstly - you should catch this `false` value and not assume `$result` has data.

Secondly - `var_dump()` the query you are running, run that in PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Did var_dump() and got this: resource(4) of type (mysql result)

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to have solved it:

```
$pin = $_POST["pin"];

function validated_pin($pin)
{   

    $pin = mysql_real_escape_string($pin);  // SECURITY!
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        return 'This pin has already been used';
            } else {
        return 'This pin is available for use';
             } 
}
```

Still facing the issue of it saying "Already been used" before I execute any code.